# When is it appropriate to use the Invariant Culture?

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

Is it inappropriate to use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)? And, if used, would it affect any global settings?

```vb
Dim hh As Decimal = 123456789.123456

' Is this an appropriate usage?
Dim ll As String = hh.ToString("N4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture bad?

It entirely depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to format values to be *machine*-readable, it's almost always the right thing to do. If you're trying to format them for *users*, it may well be inappropriate.

> Will it effect the global culture?

Specifying the invariant culture in a method call won't change the current thread's current culture, if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 6):

> Is using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture bad?

No.  It exists for a reason.  It allows you to parse text in a consistent, reliable manner, no matter what the current system culture happens to be.

However, it shouldn't be used (normally) to parse *user input*, but rather parsing text where you know it was written in the same manner that InvariantCulture expects.